# In d3.js v4 zoom functionality I am having an issue where when i zoom out and then pan the chart goes out of the viewport instantly

Tags: zooming, data-visualization, d3.js

Here's my code:

```
var zoom = d3.zoom()
.scaleExtent([0.3, 10])
.on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
    svg.attr("transform", function(d){ 
        var transform = d3.zoomTransform(this);
        return transform;
    });
}

var svg = d3.select("#app")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
  .call(zoom);

var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");
```

There is no problem if the scaleExtent is [1,10]. The problem only occurs when it is below 1 for the x. If you pan after zooming below 1 the chart translates to some very high value and disappears from the viewport. And its not possible to bring it back.

I have gone through the api docs and didnt find any solution. Please help.
Your help will highly appreciated.

[image: rectangle with force layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of panning and zooming on the group which holds the rectangle.

```
svg.attr("transform", function(d){ 
    var transform = d3.zoomTransform(this);
    return transform;
});
```

do transform on the rectangle

```
function zoomed() {
  rect.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RNRleAuRJJqB26sBSbJx?p=preview)

Or

Better if you add another group(say layer). And in that group add the rectangle. Then apply transform on the group(layer) like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/RDgrINy7DkEBRD7pcWRD?p=preview)

**EDIT**

Since you dont want the rectangle to zoom and pan but be a reciever to all mouse events.

Add the rectangle to the svg group like below:

```
var rect = svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .style("fill", "red")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");
```

Now create a layer

```
var layer = svg.append("g");
```

Add all that you want to zoom and pan in the new layer:

```
var circle = layer.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 100 )
    .attr("cy",  10)
    .attr("r",  10)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");

var circle = layer.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 100 )
    .attr("cy",  50)
    .attr("r",  10)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");


var circle = layer.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 300 )
    .attr("cy",  50)
    .attr("r",  10)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("pointer-events", "all");
```

on zoom + pan apply the transform on the group like this

```
function zoomed() {
  layer.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}
```

code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/RDgrINy7DkEBRD7pcWRD?p=preview)

Comment: Maybe I wasnt clear. The group g contains nodes and links in a force layout. I want all of it to zoom in and out. The rectangle is simply there to catch all mouse events. So I want the g to zoom in and out and not the rectangle. and when i do this the translate for the g goes to an abnormally high number

Comment: check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/RDgrINy7DkEBRD7pcWRD?p=preview this should nail it..In this i have added a group called layer....all circles and all that which need to zoom and pan go in there. The rectangle stands behind to catch all mouse events..